# What are the semantics of each InputType constant?

Tags: android, textview, android-input-method

You can set a `TextView`'s `inputType` to one of the values from `InputType` to hint that the typed-in text should be a person's name, phone number, &c. Even if the input method doesn't respect this hint, the `TextView` uses a `KeyListener` and/or `TransformationMethod` to ensure that only relevant characters can be entered, or to have effects like masking the password. Even the flags are more than just hints: they can change the behaviour of the `TextView` significantly (the most obvious example being `EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE`).

Google's documentation is very vague about the actual effect of each `inputType`. What characters are actually permitted in each case? How does this vary by locale, if at all? Even if there is no *documented* answer, and it's liable to change between versions, I'd still like to know the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can find this out by inspecting the source of the `*KeyListener` classes, though of course this may be changed in different versions or by manufacturer or carrier customizations. The below is based on the AOSP 4.3 source. These are only the effects that each type has on Android itself: input methods also use the types as hints to better predict what the user is likely to type. For example, although `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PERSON_NAME` only has the effect of disabling spell-check, the IM might respond to this type by auto-completing from a dictionary of common names instead of from a language dictionary.

To experiment with input types and IME options, I hacked up a quick app that lets you select them from a list in a GUI, so you don't have to edit an XML layout and rebuild an app to do it. If you want to find out more, or check how they interact with a given IM app, [download **IM prove** free from Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shadowburst.improve).

## `TYPE_NULL`

This one is actually documented:

> This should be interpreted to mean that the target input connection is not rich, it can not process and show things like candidate text nor retrieve the current text, so the input method will need to run in a limited "generate key events" mode, if it supports it. Note that some input methods may not support it, for example a voice-based input method will likely not be able to generate key events even if this flag is set.

This makes it sounds like it's for cases where you're not editing text, but pressing a key on the IM will do some action directly. But in fact it hides the IM completely. From the app's point of view, you almost never want this: set it if you only want a hardware keyboard to be able to enter text.

From the IM's point of view, you'll get this type passed to `onStartInput` a lot, usually when Android is about to hide the IM because a different activity is coming to the foreground. You want responding to this input type to be fast. There could be two reasons why it works this way, but someone involved with the design would have to confirm why:-

1. It could be to let the IM know that editing is completely finished in that window (unlike `onFinishInput`, which merely means the IM is being hidden), so it can free memory used for dictionaries and the like until editing restarts.
2. It could be part of what allows a hardware keyboard to use arrow keys for scrolling, menu accelerator keys, and so on, even when no text input is taking place.

## Classes

### Numeric types

`TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER` gives you the digits 0-9. In addition, adding `TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED` lets you have `+` or `-`, but only as the first character. Adding `TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL` lets you have `.` in any position, but only once. You *can* have both signed and decimal. As far as I can tell, this *isn't* localized, so the allowed characters are the same even for locales where `.` is the thousands separator and `,` is the decimal point, or for locales with different number characters.

`TYPE_CLASS_PHONE` lets you have the digits 0-9, as well as any of `#*+-(),/N.;` and space. You can have those characters in any order and any number of times: there's no formatting check.

`TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME | TYPE_DATETIME_VARIATION_DATE` lets you have the digits 0-9 as well as any of `/-.`. Again, there's no extra check for formatting, so you can have them in any order.

`TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME | TYPE_DATETIME_VARIATION_TIME` lets you have the digits 0-9 as well as `:` and any of `amp` (for writing "am" or "pm", but you can use them in any order and position). Slightly perversely, you can't have space or . for "3 pm" or "2 p.m." or even "2.30". Again, it doesn't seem to be localized.

`TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME | TYPE_DATETIME_VARIATION_NORMAL` gets you 0-9 as well as `:/-`, space, and `amp`. This notably doesn't include `.` even though it's allowed in a date.

Based on the above observations, I can't say I'd recommend using any of the above classes. They all seem to have major absences and prevent localization. The above are the only classes with character restrictions.

`TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD` does as you'd expect: it uses a `TransformationMethod` to obscure the typed characters.

### Text types

In `TYPE_CLASS_TEXT`, setting `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS` or `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_SUBJECT` makes a press of the enter key move focus to the next field instead of inserting a newline.

`TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_FILTER` will prevent the input method going to full-screen (extract) mode.

`TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD` has the obvious effect: it uses a `TransformationMethod` to obscure the typed characters. `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD` still uses the `TransformationMethod` to prevent the text being copied

All of the following text variations allow spell-checking if `TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS` is not set. That is, using an class that is not `TYPE_CLASS_TEXT` or a variation that is *not* in this list has the same effect as setting `TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS` (which is described later).

- `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL`
- `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_SUBJECT`
- `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_LONG_MESSAGE`
- `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_SHORT_MESSAGE`
- `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_EDIT_TEXT`

## Flags

The presence or absence of `InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE` has non-obvious side-effects. If the type class is *not* `TYPE_CLASS_TEXT`, it is always as if the flag were *not* set, and the `TextView` goes into single-line mode. Setting `lines` or `maxLines` to 1 only affects the way the text is displayed: it does *not* start single-line mode.

In single-line mode:-

- the ellipsize option defaults to end
- pressing enter performs the "editor action" or moves focus to the next field (just as for email addresses or subjects, above); otherwise, it inserts a newline
- pressing tab moves focus to the next field, only if `TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_IME_MULTI_LINE` is not set; otherwise it inserts a tab character
- the `imeOptions` can include an "editor action" to replace the enter key on a soft keyboard; in multi-line mode, `TextView` will add `IME_FLAG_NO_ENTER_ACTION` to the `imeOptions`
- `maxLines` is automatically set to 1
- adding a newline to the field (e.g. using `setText`) has no effect, and a carriage return is replaced with a zero-width space (U+FEFF)

`TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_*` use `TextUtils.getCapsMode` to decide whether to capitalize each character. The rules are a little baroque and are *not* locale-sensitive. AFAICT, this only takes effect if the corresponding setting is enabled in the default keyboard.

When `TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_CORRECT` is set, space, tab, newline, any Unicode "end punctuation" character, or any of `,.!?"` will trigger auto-correction of the preceding word (in this context, that's the longest sequence of Unicode letters and apostrophes). If the whole word doesn't have a correction, it continues to retry with shorter subsequences. The corrections come from a fixed system resource `com.android.internal.R.xml.autotext` and are separate from any configured spell-checker.

`TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS` (or the text variations listed earlier) stops the text being spell-checked. This prevents the spell-check suggestions list being shown, and also stops misspelled words being highlighted. The input method can still provide completions if it chooses.

## Other oddities

Long-tapping a `TextView` usually selects the tapped word, but if the input type is one of the following, it selects all of the text instead:-

- `TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER`
- `TYPE_CLASS_PHONE`
- `TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME` (any variation)
- `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_URI`
- `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS`
- `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_EMAIL_ADDRESS`
- `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_FILTER`

Comment: Note that the docs say that [`KeyListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/KeyListener.html) is *basically* only used for hard keyboards. So, this list might not be accurate for most users. `"Key presses on soft input methods are not required to trigger the methods in this listener, and are in fact discouraged to do so. The default android keyboard will not trigger these for any key to any application targeting Jelly Bean or later, and will only deliver it for some key presses to applications targeting Ice Cream Sandwich or earlier."`

Comment: @Geobits The docs do say this. But if you make a trivial app for API 18, set the `inputType` appropriately on a `EditText`, and run it with an input method of your choice (including the default), the behaviour is exactly as if a `KeyListener` of the appropriate type were filtering the keystrokes. I think the doc is saying only that the input method shouldn't go through a `KeyListener`, because they're triggered elsewhere in `TextView` or `InputMethodManager`.

Comment: I didn't say it was wrong, I'm just pointing out that since they're two separate use cases, one could change without the other being affected, so it's worth double-checking. As for the code block, I agree that it's not optimal, but block-quoting doesn't work in comments, and a huge paragraph of italics/bold is harder to read(IMO). It's the easiest way to separate the quote from my comment at a glance. If you feel strongly about it, feel free to add your opinion [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120031/212780). Ironic that *you* chose to use code formatting to chastise me about it, though.

Comment: So what does `TYPE_NULL` and `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL` and `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_EDIT_TEXT` do? And how are they different?

Comment: I've added some information about `TYPE_NULL` to my answer. Everything I know about those other two types is already in there. `NORMAL` is the default and makes the IM behave normally; `WEB_EDIT_TEXT` is for a web browser to set on web input forms, but AFAICT has no special effect within Android itself. I can see from experimenting that SwiftKey acts as if `TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES` were set, if the type is `WEB_EDIT_TEXT`, but Google Keyboard doesn't.