# When should a soft keyboard show an enter key?

Tags: android, android-input-method

This is separate from whether the app has requested an editor action: usually the editor action is displayed as a replacement for the enter key, but it's possible for an input method to offer both as alternatives.

The simple answer is, of course, "when it's possible to enter a newline". When a `TextView` is in *single-line mode*, it's not possible to enter a newline even if the keyboard shows a key: as I found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19408004/967945), Android itself treats the key as an editor action and substitutes a zero-width space for any newlines added to the `TextView`.

How can the input method tell whether newlines will be respected, or otherwise whether it's appropriate to show an enter key (as an alternative to any specified editor action)?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to check the [EditorInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo.html) object returned using the `getCurrentInputEditorInfo()` and take a best guess if showing the Enter key is apt or not.

Comment: Yeah, it's the "take a best guess" part I'm unclear about. What logic should I use to decide?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way of knowing if the TextView will accept enter as a newline character because it is entirely up to the application in which the TextView is, and frankly, I have never ever thought of enter key as just the newline character, 'enter-key' gets the job done, sometime it sends messages, sometime it just moves to the next field and sometimes it is just enters a newline. I don't know if labelling enter as done or go is any useful at all.